# Why does make utility fail to delete a file associated with an incomplete task when issuing qdel command on SGE?

Tags: bash, makefile, hpc

I have a bash script which runs a make command on a Sun Grid Engine HPC:

```
#submitscript.sh

module load program1 program2

set -a

make
```

This bash script runs a makefile which looks like:

```
# makefile
SHELL := /bin/bash

all: Variants.vcf Variants1.vcf

Variants.vcf:
    program1 inputfile > Variants.vcf

Variants1.vcf:
    program2 inputfile2 > Variants1.vcf
```

I submit the script on the HPC by issuing:

```
qsub submitscript.sh
```

When I issue qdel  to delete the task the file that is currently being written to is not deleted by make. I would have thought that the qdel command would result in the makefile exiting and deleting any target files not completely written. Can anybody explain what is happening here?

**Update**

Thank you. I realise my mistake now. Qdel is killing the entire job so as you both say make is not being allowed to clean up. When I added the line to the makefile:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR: *.vcf
```

and then put a wrong file path into the program2 line eg.

```
Variants1.vcf:
    program2 inputfile2 > /wrong/file/path/Variants1.vcf
```

the desired behaviour was shown with the partially written file being deleted on exit.

Comment: The issue is that `make` isn't being killed? Or that it isn't deleting the target files whose recipes haven't completed? The latter is likely because you haven't set [`.DELETE_ON_ERROR`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Errors).

Comment: If you kill make how can it then do the cleanup? If you killed program1 or program2 it could have a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Comments:

> If you kill make how can it then do the cleanup? If you killed program1 or program2 it could have a chance. – user2672165

Response:

> I realise my mistake now. Qdel is killing the entire job so as you both say make is not being allowed to clean up. – user1977981

I'm answering this so other users with the same problem can easily determine the answer that was provided.